# How to calculate Redis memory usage

Tags: php, redis

I have an Elasticache Redis instance on AWS and I want to monitor its memory usage and send alerts when it exceeds a certain threshold. The Redis info command provides several memory-related metrics, including

`used_memory:3651689760`

`used_memory_human:3.40G`

`used_memory_rss:3684122624`

`used_memory_rss_human:3.43G`

`used_memory_peak:3704319760`

`used_memory_peak_human:3.45G`

`used_memory_peak_perc:98.58%`

`maxmemory:20975001908`

`maxmemory_human:19.53G`

I would like to calculate the total memory usage of Redis based on these metrics and send an alert when the usage exceeds a specific percentage.

Can anyone provide guidance on how to calculate Redis memory usage based on the info command output?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INFO MEMORY` gives you the relevant information about memory related metrics. For finding out the current memory utilization, you can use `used_memory_human` which in your case is `3.4GB`

You can use the following command to find the memory usage:

```
redis-cli -h 127.0.0.1 -p 6379 INFO MEMORY | grep used_memory_human
used_memory_human:948.84K
```

There are several ways by which your can implement the alerting on top of this:
You can have a Python or shell script run every 5 minutes or so and trigger and email alert; you can also setup prometheus and alertmanager for the same

Comment: Thank you for your response! I want to find the percentage of used memory out of total memory, for that which fields I can pick from the memory section?

Comment: If you want to calculate percentage ,you need to take into account the value of the configuration MAXMEMORY. If MAXMEMORY is set to some value like 10GB or 50GB, then you can easy calculate the percentage. But if MAXMEMORY is set to 0, it means your Redis can utilize as much memory as available, so you won't be able to calculate the percentage usage effectively.